# Why minimum Inter item Spacing does not work?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I try inside of `viewDidLoad` the next code:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

but it doesn't work. What is the reason of this? Any ideas?

Comment: Does it crash? Is there a compiler error?

Comment: @Qbyte no. Nothing there =/

Comment: @Orkhan what do you expect, and what happens?

Comment: So what doesn't work exactly? Since the line spacing can be any value but not negative.

Comment: @Qbyte is zero negative? The space between rectangles is the same. I do not want these spaces around

Comment: @DánielNagy I want to set a space around rectangles to 0. I do not want these spaces around

Comment: @Orkhan and what if your view controller conforms to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and in the method collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex: set the interim space to zero instead of what you did in view did load?

Comment: @DánielNagy sorry, I did not understand you. Can you explain clearly?

Comment: @Orkhan So your viewcontroller, which contains your code  above, should conform to **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** (e.g.: MyViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout), and after that, you will need the method **collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:**, and in that method return 0.

Comment: @DánielNagy like this? `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex indexPath: NSIndexPath) { return 0 }`?

Comment: @DánielNagy but it prints me `Unexpected non-void return value in void function` error

Comment: @Orkhan sorry, this way: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

Comment: @DánielNagy unfortunately, it doesn't help me, too. There the result: http://imgur.com/7GJjCOH

Comment: @Orkhan are the cell sizes set correctly? It looks like according to your screenshot, that the width and height should be equal to the screenwidth / 2.

Comment: @DánielNagy yes, them sizes are correct =/

Answer (score 1):

You should be set direction is horizontally. You need delete the code for the reason below:

"For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same column. This spacing is used to compute how many items can fit in a single line, but after the number of items is determined, the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted upward."